# Keeping the color of list item after click

Tags: android, android-listview, listviewitem

Is there any way to keep the color of listview item after it is clicked.
the color of item should remain either or not the activty switches .

Just like the honeycomb versions list view ,we can show an fragment with keeping the color of list item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by

```
lv.setSelection(position);
```

And For set Color of selected item

```
lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
lv.setSelector( R.drawable.listselector);
```

or else you can use property in XML as

```
android:listSelector="#00000000"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

First call `listView.setOnItemClickListener();` on the `onItemClick()` method, then call `listView.setSelection(position)` and then the selected item will keep selected state.